# Executing Stored Procedure using php PDO is only returning the last result set

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, firebird

After connecting successfully, I am trying to get data from my Stored Procedures. But the below code is only returning successfully the last result set of the SP, instead of all the sets.

```
$dbh = new PDO (.....);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("EXEC ......");

$sth->execute();

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

Is there anything I need to add to my code?

Thanks.

Comment: [Calling stored procedures in PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call)

Comment: Just tried that out and didn't seem to work either. Just found out that nextRowset() is not supported by the Firebird PDO Driver.

Comment: eek! Then it's going to be a problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple rows from a Firebird stored procedure, you need to **select** from it instead of executing it. Although IIRC you would only get the first result when executing it, contrary to what you say in your question.

So use:

```
select * from your_procedure()
```